# 'Installation failed: Could not create directory.' I get this error everytime i try to download plugin in wp 4.8

Tags: wordpress, plugins, installation, cpanel

I am getting error accessing my admin panel. The error is due to plugin. I fixed the issue by renaming the plugin folder from cpanel and changed it back. Since then,i couldn't download any plugins and get the error

> Installation failed: Could not create directory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set permission on plugin folder/directory, now the user does not have permission to create folder/directory in plugin folder/directory.

You need to set permission on wp-content and all inside folder/directory to 755.

You can set permission via terminal

```
sudo chmod -R 755 wp-content
```

wp-content should me you folder path for Linux server path should be /var/www/html/project_folder/wp-content

OR

you can set permission via FTP. Right click on wp-content folder click on permission menu and set 755 permission to the folder.

Comment: This is very bad advice. You are very likely to have a hacker come upload nasty scripts to your server, before owning it all. It happened to me, and believe me, allowing anybody to write to your `wp-content` is no solution! Rather follow this advice: https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/

Comment: 777 permission is very dangerous and it means any hacker can hack your website.

Answer (score 4):

The permissions or ownership on wp-content/plugins is incorrect. That directory should have a 775 permission set.
If its already that then reapply 755 and checked “apply recursively to all directories and files.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a docker container or docker-compose, you also need to give permission to the database volume.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).