# Installation failed: Could not create directory

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem when i'm trying to update plugins or install plugins . I got a message "Installation failed: Could not create directory." so i can't update .

I also tried to grant permission chmod 777 for all wp-content folder but still not change anything . Please give me some advice . Thanks a lot

Comment: did you try change permissionto 755?
look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44670008/installation-failed-could-not-create-directory-i-get-this-error-everytime-i
is this helpful?

Comment: thanks for your comment , i tried to change permission to 777 for wp-content and wp-includes and it worked