# Cannot update plugin for WordPress on localhost on Mac

Tags: wordpress

I'm running WordPress 5.8.1 on localhost, on my Mac. I am unable to update plugins. I get this error:

Update failed: Could not create directory.

I've tried changing the permission on the wp-content folder as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44670008/installation-failed-could-not-create-directory-i-get-this-error-everytime-i) like this:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 wp-content
```

but it didn't work. I still get the error message.

I also tried this

```
sudo chown -R _www wp-dir
sudo chmod -R g+w wp-dir
```

still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Managed to find the issue. Apache uses a different username so this command was ok:

```
sudo chown -R _www wp-dir
```

But my username wasn't _www (hence my error)

you can find the apache username in the etc/httpd.conf file